# Set object array-type property value using reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

I am trying to generate some generic code that can create C# objects from text generated by another system. The object is to be used for a method call - the method call is also going to be done by reflection. When I am creating this method parameter object, I could not figure out how to instantiate and assign values to a property that is array type. I can use the setValue to assign to "name" in the code sample below, but how to assign values to the array?

```
class Car {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Door[] doors { get; set; }
}

class Door {
    public int index { get; set; }
    public bool isDusty { get; set; }
}

public object createMethodParameter(Vehicle<T> v)

    object methodParameter;

    Type type = v.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] properties;
    MethodInfo[] mi = type.GetMethods();

    ParameterInfo[] pi;

    foreach (var method in mi)
    {
        if ("create".Equals(method.Name.ToLowerInvariant())) // look for the create method
        {
            pi = method.GetParameters();
            foreach (var param in pi)
            {
                returnValue = Activator.CreateInstance(param.ParameterType);
                properties = param.ParameterType.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
                    {
                        // how to create the doors array on the car??
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        property.SetValue(methodParameter, "Porsche", null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return methodParameter;
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to get the type of the array, call `Array.CreateInstance` or something similar, fill the array, set the property, etc.  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: The "Array.CreateInstance" part. I thought I needed the Activator class for that. SLaks answer helped me. I will accept it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Array.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType.GetElementType(), 4)
```